# How to replace 2 spaces middle of string to a character and a space in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have string as shown below. In dart `replaceFirst()` its removes all whitespace and it's not what i want. My question is: How to **replace 2 spaces middle of string to a character and a space** in Dart?

```
Example:

 - Original: String _myText = "abc  23";
 - Expected Text: "abcd 23"
 - Result with replaceFirst() : "abcd23"
```

Comment: Please share the code line where you have used `replaceFirst()`.

Comment: i used ```"abc  23".replaceFirst(' ', 'd')```

Comment: I tried this out. It is working fine. Result is expected text - _abcd 23_

Comment: replaceFirst code gives me the expected result on the DartPad

Comment: Thanks for your interest, i did resolve this, i think this error from my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"abc  23".replaceFirst(' ', 'd')` returns the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Use wrap widget may be your problem would be solve

Eg:

```
     Wrap( child:Text(“hii    Byy”))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
String _myText = "abc  23";
_myText.replaceAll('  ', ' '); // it returns the string   'abc 23'
```

Answer (score 0):

`"abc  23".replaceFirst(' ', 'd')` returns the expected output. Are you sure, you pass a single white space character and not two as the first parameter of the `replaceFirst` method ?